# Draw circle and remove the selected area in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to draw a circle and make it as transparent by removing it. I used the Elliptical Marquee Tool but it cannot be drawn with the same size of the circle that I want to remove. Is there any way to adjust the circle size after it get drawn?

[image]

Comment: Already tried Select > Transform selection? Or making the selection by color and contrast? I guess the Quick Selection Tool would work, even the Magic Wand. But you may need to apply Refine Edge.

Comment: It's fine to do when you're downsizing, but not when upsizing. It's the same as when you're resizing images. The edge quality suffers way less when you're making it smaller and gets drastically worse the bigger you make it. You'd be way better off taking that existing `Ellipse 1` layer and perhaps making a Duplicate of it (Cmd+J), Free Transforming it (Cmd+T), Making a selection out of it (Cmd+Left-click on the thumbnail).

Comment: That said when I'm resizing a selection, I like to turn on Quick Mask (Q) (...or bottom left of the toolbar) and then turn on Free Transform (Cmd+T). In this case, it works very similar to Transform Selection, but the difference is that I can see the edge quality as I'm transforming it because of the way Quick Mask overlay shows translucency.

Comment: @user287001 using quick selection tool reduce the smoothness of the circle line

Comment: Fix it with Refine Edge.

Comment: erm.. use the Shape tool with a fill and a stroke and apply a layer mask to knock out the center. Am I missing something? Using raster here seems counter productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to achieve so please forgive me if I got it wrong, but if you use the Ellipse Tool you can set the fill to none, just apply a stroke. If you then also want an inner circle duplicate the Ellipse shape layer, rescale it but while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> after you begin dragging, to constrain the circle and scale from the centre, then set the stroke of the inner circle to a different colour.

Example

[image]

Comment: Also note if you find yourself doing work like this in Photoshop often, ultimately it might be better to have a look at using vector image editing software instead, such as Illustrator/Inkscape/CorelDraw, etc.

Comment: Brilliant!! I never have a thought of doing this. Thank you!